# Hive 0.13 bucketed map join

Tags: join, dictionary, hive, bucket

Has anyone in history successfully performed a bucketed map join in Hive 13? There is limited documentation on BMJs (http://www.openkb.info/2014/11/understanding-hive-joins-in-explain.html#.VVuZZpNViko and https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/download/attachments/27362054/Hive%2BSummit%2B2011-join.pdf). They seem wonderful, but I can not get them to work.

If I understand correctly, I must start my command with the following parameters:

```
SET hive.optimize.bucketmapjoin=true;
```

This will cause Hive to automatically convert my lazy, super slow, regular old reducer join to a lithe (svelte even?), fast-finishing, bucketed map join. Maybe I am missing some parameters here?

My tables are both bucketed properly. They are both bucketed into 1024 buckets (could this be too many?). The small table has a bucket size of around 15MB and the large table has an average bucket size of arount 10GB.

Here's what my command looks like:

```
SET hive.optimize.bucketmapjoin=true;

SELECT
   EV.advertiser_id,
   EV.pixel_id,
   RDB.segment_id
FROM 
   rakuten_segment_index2_bucketed_event_logs_ddp EV
   JOIN rakuten_sir_bucketed_rdb RDB
      ON EV.mm_uuid = RDB.mm_uuid
WHERE 
   EV.days = 90 AND RDB.days = 90;
```

This command results in a slow and steady reducer join. It runs fine, but very slowly.

One thing to note is that these tables are partitioned. I am only interested in joining these tables where the value of the partition(days) = 90. Could the fact that these tables are partitioned be spoiling the bucketed map join?

I have also tried setting a map join hint explicitly with `/*+MAPJOIN(EV)*/`.
This forces a normal mapjoin, not a bucketed mapjoin. Hive tries to load the entire small(er) table into a hashmap and pretty quickly runs out of memory.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work eventually. Seems to have had something to do with `hive.mapjoin.bucket.cache.size`.

Try setting this to a higher number than it's default (10 or 100 I think). My job ran fine as follows:

```
SET hive.optimize.bucketmapjoin=true;
set hive.exec.reducers.max = 30000;
set hive.mapjoin.bucket.cache.size=100000000;

SELECT /*+MAPJOIN(EV)*/
   EV.advertiser_id,
   EV.pixel_id,
   RDB.segment_id
FROM 
   tbl_a EV
   JOIN tbl_b RDB
      ON EV.mm_uuid = RDB.mm_uuid
WHERE 
   EV.days = 90 AND RDB.days = 90;
```

Note: the `mapjoin` hint is necessary as well.

Comment: >> thanks for nothing ..  You're welcome..  I was about to upvote your question and your answer .. but now am thinking twice about it.

Comment: OK I see you removed that statement.  I'm upvoting now - your Q&A are after all good quality.